# How to convert percentage to z-score of normal distribution in C/C++?

Tags: c++, statistics, normal-distribution, anomaly-detection

The goal is to say: "These values lie within a band of 95 % of values around the mean in a normal distribution."

Now, I am trying to convert percentage to z-score, so then I can get the precise range of values. Something like `<lower bound , upper bound>` would be enough.

So I need something like

```
double z_score(double percentage) {
   // ...
}

// ...

// according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68–95–99.7_rule
z_score(68.27) == 1
z_score(95.45) == 2
z_score(99.73) == 3
```

I found an [article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560644/calculate-z-score-given-probability-using-erfinv) explaining how to do it with a [function from boost library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_erf/error_inv.html), but

```
double z_score( double percentage ) {
    return - sqrt( 2 ) / boost::math::erfc_inv( 2 * percentage / 100 );
}
```

does not work properly and it returns weird values.

```
z_score(95) == 1.21591 // instead of 1.96
```

Also the boost library is kinda heavy and I plan to use it for Ruby gem, so it should be as lightweight as possible.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Boost is C++. Why the C tag? And what makes you think "boost library is kinda heavy"?

Comment: I can do it in both C or C++. And I don't need/want to use boost library. By heavy, I meant it has like 500 MB. And I don't want to use it for Ruby library, unless I have to.

Comment: Please only tag the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: I have the rest of the code ready in both C and C++, so I can use implementation of that z-score function in both languages. I wanted to tag both languages, because they are related to the problem and I could get more responses.

Comment: I have a code, that calculates normal distribution from numbers. So I have all the information like mean, stddev, etc. I have all the rest of the code ready and working. All I need is to convert that 95 % to z-score of 1.96 acording to 65-95-99 rule -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68–95–99.7_rule

Of course I need z-score values for other percentages too.

Comment: Your `z_score` function is dividing `sqrt(2)` by `erfc_inv( 2 * percentage / 100 )` instead of multiplying. Also the formula you used is for the one-sided percentile to z-score conversion, but you want a two-sided percentile to z-score conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say you were "close enough".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp>
#include <cmath>

double z_score(double percentage) {
    return sqrt(2) * boost::math::erf_inv(percentage / 100);
}

int main() {
    #define _(x)  std::cout << x << " " << z_score(x) << "\n"
    _(68.27);
    _(95.45);
    _(99.73);
}
```

outputs:

```
68.27 1.00002
95.45 2
99.73 2.99998
```

I do not know how you got that `-` in front, and that it's `erf>>c<<_inv` and that it's `sqrt(2)` divided by. From [here wiki Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage) I read that:

```
p <- this is probability, ie. your input
u <- mean value
o <- std dev
n <- the count of std deviations from mean, ie. 1, 2, 3 etc.
p = F(u + no) - F(u + no) = fi(n) - fi(-n) = erf(n / sqrt(2))
p = erf(n / sqrt(2))
erf_inv(p) = n / sqrt(2)
erf_inv(p) * sqrt(2) = n
n = sqrt(2) * erf_inv(p)
```

> Also the boost library is kinda heavy

A 5 min search resulted in [this](https://github.com/antelopeusersgroup/antelope_contrib/blob/master/lib/location/libgenloc/erfinv.c) and [this](https://github.com/lakshayg/erfinv/blob/master/erfinv.c) C implementations `erf_inv`.